# How do I control the <?xml ?> part of xml serialization with .NET?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I am using this method to serialize my object:

```
public static string XmlSerialize(object o)
{
    var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(stringWriter, o);
    string xml = stringWriter.ToString();
    stringWriter.Close();
    return xml;
}
```

It makes XML that starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<MyObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

So, how do I change the encoding to Windows-1252 and set standalone = yes?
Additionally, how to I get the object to exclude the xmlns value?

I've seen a couple similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933664/net-xml-serialization-without-xml-root-node), but I was hoping it might be simpler for me, maybe by setting some attributes somewhere?

Update 2: After looking at John's answer and comments, and thinking about this more, I decided to just make a second method. I don't think that creating this wacky custom xml just for a 3rd party on one occasion should be called something as generic as "XmlSerialize" in the first place.

So, I created a second method that takes an XML document and first, removes the one namespace element like this:

```
xElement.Attributes().Where(a => a.IsNamespaceDeclaration && a.Value == "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema").Remove();
```

then, it it writes it to XML with John's code. Finally it returns that xml, following the output from this:

```
new XDeclaration("1.0", "Windows-1252", "yes").ToString()
```

And that's ugly, but it gets me exactly what I need for this 3rd party to understand my XML.

Comment: Really, use `XmlReader.Create` and `XmlWriter.Create` instead of `XmlTextReader` and `XmlTextWriter`. Also, you need to be putting these things into `using` blocks.

Comment: Ultimately I went with your code. But just wondering, as long as I close everything, isn't that just as good as using blocks?

Comment: No. `using` blocks make sure the objects are disposed, even when exceptions happen.

Comment: Oh! So the only way to get that out of Close() would be to use try...finally then? If that is the case, then I totally get the point.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static string XmlSerialize(object o)
{
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
                           {
                               Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252),
                               OmitXmlDeclaration = true
                           };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(o.GetType());
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, o);
        }
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

This won't get rid of the xsd: namespace, but then, why do you want to?

---

**Update:** It seems that whenever you use a `StringWriter`, you get UTF-16, even if you use an `XmlWriter` on top of it with encoding set. Next step would be to write out to a `MemoryStream`. But that raises the question of why you want to return a string. For instance, if you're going to just turn around and output the string to a stream, then we should output directly to this stream. Same for a `TextWriter`.

Comment: I am using an API and they have specified that the xsd thing should not be in there. Why they don't want it and why they can't seem to just ignore it I have no idea.

Comment: John, I do not want to get rid of the xml declaration. I want to keep it and change what is outputted.

Comment: Get rid of the OmitXmlDeclaration = true, and you should have the declaration back. You need to kick your API people **really hard** if they choke on the xsd declaration. It will be necessary if xsi:type needs to be specified. If we don't all follow standards, soon XML will not be standard at all.

Comment: Even without OmitXmlDeclaration, the declaration ends up being <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>. I need it to be the windows encoding, with standalone="yes".

Comment: I guess I could just omit the declaration as you originally suggested and prepend:
new XDeclaration("1.0", "Windows-1252", "yes").ToString()
to the output? This whole thing is ugly anyway.

Comment: Upvoted; but I think your post demonstrates the bad points of the `var` keyword. Seems like you're totally misusing it here.

Comment: Please elaborate. What's your problem with it?

Comment: `var` should only be used with LINQ, IMHO. You clearly know what object you're getting back there; I see no reason for `var`, only laziness. But probably pointless arguing. Just an observation.

Comment: My reason for using `var` in most cases is the freedom to change the returned type without having to change the declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.aspx) instead of a StringWriter. Here is an extract from some of my code with your encoding set.

```
XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
textWriter.Namespaces = false;
```

Comment: `XmlTextWriter` should no longer be used, as of .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I got the encoding to work by using an XmlWriter with XMLWriterSettings. Here is a sample:

```
...  
// My object type was from a class generated by xsd.  
XmlSerializer xms = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SomeType));  
SomeType objSt;
using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\SomeFile.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{    
  using(XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(fs))  // Supposed to preserve encoding.  
  {  
    objSt = (SomeType)xms.Deserialize(xr);  
  }    
}  

...  
...  // Do some stuff, change some attribute values.  
...  

XmlWriterSettings xsw= new XmlWriterSettings();  
xsw.Indent= true;  
xsw.NewLineOnAttributes= true;  
xsw.Encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);  
using(XmlWriter xwXsw = XmlWriter.Create("C:\SomeFile_Changed.xml",xsw))
{    
  xms.Serialize(xwXsw, objSt);  
}  
...  
...  // Finish up and get out.
...
```

For some reason, I was able to get it all to work once just using the XmlSerializer object and serializing with a TextWriter, since according to MS help for XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader) "The XmlReader automatically detects and uses the encoding specified by the XML document." Then I started playing with the XmlWriterSettings and broke something....

Comment: A belated -1 for not putting your FileStream, `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` into `using` blocks.

Comment: Cool - but the comment explicitly states "without exception handling or "using"". Not sure why I did it that way - long time ago. Did not mean to hurt your feelings :)

Comment: Which comment are you referring to?

Comment: Ok, so why not add the `using` blocks and I'll remove the downvote? Don't do any exception handling because there's nothing to "handle".

Comment: OK - done. I think it makes sense. I had to dig through some old folders to even find the original code, and glad I did. That was part of a utility I wrote to tweak VS project files, and I nearly tossed it. I was way more proficient in C# back then - I have been focused on Objective C since then.