# XML Serialization with .NET

Tags: .net, xml, serialization

I'm tryng to serialize an object to XML by using C# with the following code:

```
            memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            Serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

My problem is that this produce the following output in the  part of the document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

And I want to have the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
```

Does anybody know how to include both the "encoding" and "standalone" attribute?

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429593/how-do-i-control-the-xml-part-of-xml-serialization-with-net), but it seems that is not producing the output I need.

Thanks!

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429593/how-do-i-control-the-xml-part-of-xml-serialization-with-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass ();
// fill instance 

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer (typeof (MyClass));
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings ();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
// next two settings are optional
settings.Indent = true;
settings.IndentChars = "    ";

using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create ("test.xml", settings)) {
    writer.WriteRaw ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\r\n");
    serializer.Serialize (writer, instance);
}
```

**UPDATED**: By the way if you don't want to have

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

as attribute of the root elements in the XML file and have no namespaces at all you produce you can use `[XmlRoot(Namespace="")]` as atribute of your calss `MyClass` and replace line

```
serializer.Serialize (writer, instance);
```

with the lines

```
XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces ();
namespaces.Add (string.Empty, string.Empty);
serializer.Serialize (writer, instance, namespaces);
```

Comment: For reference `settings.IndentChars = "\t";` will also work (each indent equals a tab)

Comment: @maxp: Yes I know, but I prefer to create XML files with blanks instead of tabulator. I did the same if I create XML files in any Text editors too. So it's the matter of the taste only.

Answer (score 0):

Is this tagged as serializable? If yes do you have the properties you want public? Maybe you should also post your source of (this)

Here is a good starting point: [LINK](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/objserial.aspx)