# Not sure how to send complex data using Web Services

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I've looked at quite a few of the questions on the site, but I'm still having trouble fulling understanding where to begin.

I've never done anything with webservices before, so bear with me.

The current project I've been assigned is to write a webservice that queries a database and returns the data back to the client. (using .NET 2008 programming in C#)

So far, I've been able to do basic data types no problem, but I'm not 100% sure where to go from there. I've been returning an XmlDocument type, but I'm not sure that that's the best way, or even the correct way to do it.

Currently creating an ASP.NET Web service, though it's been suggested I use a WCF Web service.

Can anyone shed light on where to go from here? Or perhaps a a link to a tutorial on sending and recieving large amounts of data via webservices?

**EDIT:** The answers are great so far, but I'm still not 100% sure how to answer. I think the webservice will be interacted with a combination of client programs, but also websites, if that is all possible... That's how new I am to this.

Comment: Big thanks to all who replied. Ryan, Mike and David especially

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer that was most helpful by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Before I provide additional updates, what's your data access layer like?  Are you using straight ADO.NET, or are you going through an ORM like LINQ-to-SQL, EF or NHibernate?  Just curious.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure. I just started at the job, and my boss just dropped this one me in my first week. I'm not really familiar with any of the technology just yet, though he's now telling me that the project is still in the process of being approved, so it'll be shelved for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the structure of the data that you're sending back to the client, I wouldn't recommend using `XmlDocument` as the return type.  It will add a lot of unnecessary bulk to your response.

You really didn't state the protocol that you want to support, but if you're transporting data via HTTP, then sending your data back to the client as a JSON-formatted string would streamline it better.

You can define that you're returning your complex type formatted as JSON like this:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate="GetComplexObject/{id}")]
public MyComplexType GetComplexObject(int id){
  //do work to get your object
  return myObject;
}
```

WCF will take care of serializing your object as JSON if `MyComplexType` is defined as a `DataContract`...

```
[DataContract]
public class MyComplexType{
  [DataMember]
  String Name {get;set;}
}
```

If you're looking for REST-ful services, then WCF is probably the preferred approach using the WebHttp functionality.

The WCF team put together a [great series](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/01/06/introducing-wcf-webhttp-services-in-net-4.aspx) of walk-throughs on using WCF WebHttp (which is new to .NET 4).  They assume a little knowledge of web http programming, but they're pretty good and hopefully help put you on the right track.

I hope this helps!!  Good luck.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if I were to pull 5000 records from a database, that have 120 columns, it would break down everything into a string and sending as such?

Comment: Sure.  It would be a very big string...but probably a lot smaller than the XML representation.

Comment: You may also want to take a look at WCF Data Services if you need some of the functionality that it provides -- paging, querying, projecting, etc.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106.aspx

Comment: I think you, Mike and Ryan have given me a really good headstart on where to go from here.

Comment: some questions: if MyComplexType is predefined, how do I take into account that not all the databases I'm accessing with have the same number of columns? How would I have return ever changing ComplexTypes?

Comment: Answered my own question there, turns out Ryans link provided me with an answer because the WCF data contract allows dataset's because they're serializable via, which is great. The only problem now is that it seems that I can't use JSON because we have a "pre-server" to the database that can't read JSON.

Can I change ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json to XML?

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

WCF uses this concept of a data contract - which provides serialization help on complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send data back to client it's throught xml, because almost all languages know how to handle xml document.

If you want to return something that it's in some way language dependent is't not worst to implement if you want your web service to be implemented using virtually all languages posible.

Another posibility is to return json objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use WCF there is a tutorial available at : http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx .

In general, [this article](http://williamsportwebdeveloper.com/cgi/wp/?p=494) gives a walk through of building an ASP.NET web service that sends JSON.

JSON is faster than XML, and is becoming a standard for most new web services.  I highly recommend the [JSON.NET library](http://json.codeplex.com/) for JSON serialization.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I have implemented this using a regular ASPX.NET web service:

1. Have the same underlying object libraries on the client and the server and functions to translate the data from the web service object to the client object.
2. Have the same underlying object libraries on the client and the server and pass data to/from the server as a string representation of the data object (usually XML format, but could be JSON or another similar format)

The first option I found is VERY cumbersome. The web service will claim that its versions of the libraries are unique, even if you have the same classes/objects on both the server and the client. Even if the namespace is the same, the object returned from the web service will have the web service namespace in it somewhere, so you have to write functions to convert them. I know of a way to fix this, but it is not worth the effort, at least not for me.

The second option is the one I am using right now. I again have one library on both client and server. It has objects that get and hold data from the database. I then have generic utility functions that serialize objects to and from XML strings. When I send data from the server I serialize it to an XML string on the server and deserialize it at the client. I do the reverse when sending data to the server. I also break up large amounts of data being passed to/from the web service to reduce errors and data transfer time.

WCF may be better. Never used it. But the above is what I have done with standard web services.

Comment: When you say "XML strings" do you mean just converting the XML document or elements into a string via something like .toString()?

Comment: I use XML serialization to serialize a given object to a string. Instead of serializing to a file, I serialize to a string. Strings pass easily across the web. Check out my answer in the following link for the serialization code (I can give you the deserialization code if you want it as well). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118761/create-xml-string-for-web-service/5118886#5118886

Comment: This might be an idea, my only concern is that I'd be returning a dataset that could be as big as 5000 records and up to 100 columns each record.

Comment: Wow. Yah, it shouldn't be too much of an issue to a point. 5000 is a lot. What I am doing currently is getting a list of the record IDs and then pulling each record individually, although there are not a whole lot of records to return from my DB. Doing this for a large number of records would take a while in any case. Maybe you can do it asynchronously. Just some thoughts.