# C#: Modifying the header of an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, infopath

I am creating an XML file in C# using a XSD Schema of an InfoPath form.

When I save the IP form without using the code, I get an XML file with the following header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?mso-infoPathSolution solutionVersion="1.0.0.113" productVersion="14.0.0" PIVersion="1.0.0.0" href="file:///\\Hmfp\mcs-shared\PMU\PMU-shared\Tests\QF%207.5%20PMU%20Project%20Outline%20Form%20F1.0.xsn" name="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:infopath:QF-7-5-PMU-Project-Outline-Form-F1-0:-myXSD-2010-07-22T07-48-32" ?>
<?mso-application progid="InfoPath.Document"?>
<my:myFields...
```

And this file is recognized by InfoPath and uses the correct XSD, thus displaying the XML data in the correct form.

But when I use the code, I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<myFields...
```

And this is not recognized nor opened directly by InfoPath; so I would like to insert the two  tags in order to keep that functionality, so that the users do not see the difference.

My line of thought is to modify the XML file after it has already been created, saved and closed.

It would be very nice if you could help :D. Thanks in advance..

EDIT: I've finally been able to achieve what I wanted. I made use of both **MainMa's** and **dahlbyk's** answers and came up with something that works:

- I let the file get saved like before
- I created an `XmlReader` object from the file
- I loaded the `XmlReader` into an `XmlDocument` object
- I created an `XmlProcessingInstruction` object using `XmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction`
- I inserted that `PI` in the `XmlDoc` using `xmlDoc.InsertAfter(thePI, XmlDoc.FirstChild)`
- I then created a second `PI` object
- Which I inserted using `xmlDoc.InsertAfter(thePI, XmlDoc.FirstChild.NextSibling)`
- Then I saved the XmlDoc in the file, overwriting it

Anyway, your answers helped me understand many things, which made me find the answer, so thank you very much!!

Comment: Is the XML generated by an InfoPath API or are you using one of the .NET XML APIs?

Comment: I guess that would be a .NET XML API, using an ASP.NET Web Service, with C# code.

I use System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer with the XSD Schema, then I write to a FileStream object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first three lines of your first code sample are called *XML processing instructions* (PI). So if you are creating your output XML with `XmlDocument`, you can use [XmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createprocessinginstruction.aspx) method to add the required PI.

If you are serializing into XML, you can also use [XmlTextWriter.WriteProcessingInstruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter.writeprocessinginstruction.aspx) just before serializing the object.

If for some reasons, you cannot do that, you can also save the file, open it and insert two PI after the first line break, but I **highly discourage** you to do that, since it will make your code difficult to maintain in future, and slow things down.

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick response.

The second option seems very interesting to me; the class created for the XSD Schema is called myFields; so I have a WebMethod called SubmitForm which uses an instance "newForm" of this class.

How do I create the XmlTextWriter instance with this?

Sorry if this seems stupid, but this is the first time (and maybe even last) that I am using .NET and XML. I just have some vague notions and I am doing this by searching everything on Google :D.

Comment: OK, I've been able to create the XmlTextWriter instance, and I've even written the PI; however it appends the PI at the end of the file, when it should have been at the top.

I must say that I first created a TextWriter instance from the file I already created, then an XmlTextWriter instance from that one.

Comment: If it appends the PI, it probably means that you are calling `WriteProcessingInstruction` after you serialize the object. If so, call it *before* serialization.

Comment: You can use a following workaround: include the three lines with `WriteProcessingInstruction` (ie. including the XML declaration), and use something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933664/net-xml-serialization-without-xml-root-node/955612#955612. It must be a more appropriate way to do things, but I can't figure out how to do it so fast.

Comment: Let's say I've been able to create an `XmlDocument` instance with the file. Can you now show me how to add the PI's please?

Comment: If you have an instance of `XmlDocument`, use `XmlDocument.CreateProcessingInstruction` (follow the first link in my answer for further information). Then save your document with `XmlDocument.Save` method.

Comment: Yep, that's what I did finally, the `CreateProcessingInstruction` returns a node that must then be inserted in the `XmlDocument`.

Thanks very much for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

I would try making an `XmlWriter` for your `FileStream`, use `WriteProcessingInstruction()` to add your headers, then pass the writer into the appropriate overload of `Serialize()` to capture the rest of the output.

Comment: Finally I came to using this solution in fact, but I still have the problem of the PI's getting put before the `<?xml...` itself.. :(