# XML declaration not coming in output

Tags: .net

I am using

```
    Dim myXPathDocument As New XPathDocument("C:\input")
    Dim myXslTransform As New XslCompiledTransform()
    Dim writer As New Xml.XmlTextWriter("C:\output.xml", Nothing)
    myXslTransform.Load("C:\XSLTFile.xsl")
    Debugger.Break()

    myXslTransform.Transform(myXPathDocument, Nothing, writer)
    writer.Close()

    Dim stream As New StreamReader("C:\output.xml")

    Console.Write("**This is result document**" & vbLf & vbLf)
    Console.Write(stream.ReadToEnd)
```

My XSLT File starts like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"  indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/name">
<myname>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</myname>
</xsl:template>
```

My XML File is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <name>
    ....
      ....
 </name>
```

My output file is like without any  XML header declaration
The transformation is fine and I am getting the required result. 
Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933664/net-xml-serialization-without-xml-root-node) use the settings of the XmlWriter to emit the Header.

Comment: Actually I do not want to emit header.I want header in output and I am not getting it.The post says about emitting header.

Comment: I do not understand your question/problem. Please give an example.

Comment: I want <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
header in my output file which is not coming.

Comment: Emitting means to send to the output. It is different from 'omitting' which means to leave out.