# How can I skip xml declaration when serializing?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm trying to output a xml file without xml head like 
I tried:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();
XmlSerializer xs=new XmlSerializer(t);
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(@"company.xml",
                                        new XmlWriterSettings() { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = true });
xs.Serialize(xw,obj);
xw.Close();
```

But it's still outputing  in the xml file.
I don't want string tricks. Any ideas?

Comment: Why you want do something like this, i am just curious :) ?

Comment: found something similar on so, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933664/net-xml-serialization-without-xml-root-node.

Comment: Maybe outputing some fragments, that are later added to a document? Or maybe sending XML fragments via sockets like XMPP does? A lot of use for that :)

Comment: Don't forget to dispose XmlWriter (better wrap in a using statement)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Set the `ConformanceLevel` to `Fragment`, like this:

```
Type t = obj.GetType();
XmlSerializer xs=new XmlSerializer(t);
XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(@"company.xml",
                              new XmlWriterSettings() { 
                                   OmitXmlDeclaration = true
                                   , ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto
                                   , Indent = true });
xs.Serialize(xw,obj);
xw.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got this error: System.InvalidOperationException: WriteStartDocument cannot be called on writers created with ConformanceLevel.Fragment.

Comment: @orange I had the same exception thrown, but setting `OmitXmlDeclaration = true` and explicitly setting `ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto` got me the expected result.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration.aspx).
There you see

> The XML declaration is always written if ConformanceLevel is set to
>   Document, even if OmitXmlDeclaration is set to true.
>
> The XML declaration is never written if ConformanceLevel is set to
>   Fragment. You can call WriteProcessingInstruction to explicitly write
>   out an XML declaration.

So you need to add

```
ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
```

Comment: I've tried with `ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment` but serialization fails. However `ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto` works like a charm (like it is written in the Diego's answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Serialize overload (Stream, Object, XmlSerializerNamespaces) and provide null as XmlSerializerNamespaces the XmlSerializer won't attempt the failing WriteStartDocument. Try:

```
xs.Serialize(xw, obj, null);
```

Comment: This also works. If you are custom serializing part of an object chain by implementing IXmlSerializable interface you already have a XmlWriter, so this solution becomes simpler.