# Change XML header namespaces before Serialization

Tags: c#, xml

I have completed the class structure necessary for SEPA xml file serialization and deserialization.

I can write the xml file to my local drive as required.

What I can't do is change the document header file to look like the 'REQUIRED' version below when the xml file is written to my local drive:

**REQUIRED** :
    < Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">

**ACTUAL** : < Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02">

So you can see what i need and what the actual output i get. I will now show you the code in my Document class and how I am attempting to change the header text.

This is the main root of the xml file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using SEPABuilder.FileSection;

namespace SEPAFileSection
{
    [XmlRoot("Document")]
    public class Document
    {
        #region Fields

        private CstmrDrctDbtInitn _cstmrDrctDbtInitn;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors

        public Document()
        {
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// Only 1 CstmrDrctDbtInitn per document
        /// </summary>
        [XmlElement("CstmrDrctDbtInitn")]
        public CstmrDrctDbtInitn CstmrDrctDbtInitn
        {
            get
            {
                if (_cstmrDrctDbtInitn == null)
                    _cstmrDrctDbtInitn = new CstmrDrctDbtInitn();

                return _cstmrDrctDbtInitn;
            }
            set
            {
                _cstmrDrctDbtInitn = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Some of the examples I have referenced from this site in an attempt to solve this issue are :

[How can I skip xml declaration when serializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332558/how-can-i-skip-xml-declaration-when-serializing)
[Including xmlns in my XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577318/xml-including-xmlns-in-my-xml-file)

... and this is a code extract of how I am attempting to change the header text after viewing these examples:

```
SEPAFileSection.Document doc = new SEPAFileSection.Document();

XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();

XNamespace ns1 = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
namespaces.Add("xsi", ns1.ToString());

XNamespace ns2 = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02";
namespaces.Add("xmlns",ns2.ToString());

//namespaces.Add(string.Empty,ns.ToString());
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SEPAFileSection.Document));
using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Xml.txt"))
{
    serializer.Serialize(writer, doc, namespaces);
}
```

So, the above code writes out my XML file fine but as you can see from the 'ACTUAL' document header above, i have an extra xmlns... i tried to use "" blank but it wouldnt allow it.

I have attached the 'Document' class here only as it is the main parent, I haven't included all the child classes as they are working fine. I hope this clarifies everything?

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a default namespace with no prefix using XMLSerializer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500111/how-do-i-add-a-default-namespace-with-no-prefix-using-xmlserializer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in addition with `XmlSerializerNamespaces`:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Document", Namespace = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02")]
public class Document
{
   ...
}
```

and remove

```
XNamespace ns2 = "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.008.001.02";
namespaces.Add("xmlns",ns2.ToString());
```

Notice that `ElementName = "Document"` is redundant.