# web api download xml + HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-web-api

I use web api to return a list of items in a xml file. It works.

This is my method :

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the product by division identifier.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">The div identifier.</param>
/// <param name="userId">The user identifier.</param>
/// <returns>A Xml file flow</returns>
[ActionName("Divisionxml")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetProductByDivisionIdXml(int id, int userId)
{
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var adoria = new Adoria(....);
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Adoria));

    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    using (var writer = new StringWriter(builder))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, adoria);

        result.Content = new StringContent(builder.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                                                                {
                                                                    FileName =
                                                                        string.Format("export_product_{0}.xml", id)
                                                                };

        return result;
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage();
}
```

The xml file is uploaded and automatically downloading by the browser. Nice.
But there is a first line in th exml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
```

I don't know why. I allow the display directly on the browser, and this line doesn't appear...

Do you have some suggestions ?

Comment: This is known as the `Xml Declaration` - as you can see it defines encoding and version used - usually you will want to keep this - it doesn't affect the document content. You can remove it during serialization e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3733699/314291

Comment: Thanks it works. I use a new XmlWriterSettings
        {
            Encoding = Encoding.UTF8,
            Indent = true,
            OmitXmlDeclaration = omitXmlDeclaration
        };

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET XML Serialization without <?xml> text declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933664/net-xml-serialization-without-xml-text-declaration)

Comment: return new HttpResponseMessage(); this line is redundant in your code. It will never be called.